# Full Calendar - No buttons showing and displaying undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Following their documentation on the [website](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/).

I have the calendar displaying, however only the month shows up, then every so often with a refresh of the page it displays the date with "undefined undefined".

I am looking for buttons to show up to change the view etc.

I have the script tags as follows

```
    <!-- Calender -->
    <link href='../css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='../css/scheduler.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src='../js/moment.js'></script>
    <script src='../js/fullcalendar.js'></script>       
    <script src='../js/scheduler.js'></script>
```

The jQuery and HTML is here:

```
<div id='calendar'></div>

<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
         themeSystem: 'bootstrap3',
         defaultView: 'listWeek',
         header: {
             left: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay custom1',
             center: 'title',
             right: 'custom2 prevYear,prev,next,nextYear'
        }
        });
      });    
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: I dont see a CDN for scheduler when trying to write up a jsfiddle. Can you give me the URL for scheduler.js that you hosted? I could then try to see if I can bring it up.

Comment: @VeluSankaran https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/schedulejs/0.6.3/schedule.js

Comment: @AidanDonnelly that file is not fullCalendar Scheduler. Here is a JSFiddle with Scheduler pasted into it. http://jsfiddle.net/toytd26b/ . Since it's a premium add-on it's not hosted on a CDN.

Comment: Anyway, as to your question... 1) you seem to have forgotten jQuery, and possibly the bootstrap CSS file as well. 2) We don't know for sure from this whether you've used compatible versions of jQuery, moment, fullCalendar and Scheduler. Please state the versions. Then check your browser console for any errors during usage.

Comment: P.S. Not sure why you've included Scheduler anyway since you don't seem to be using any of the views from it (unless you're using the vertical resource view, but we can't tell because your code sample is potentially incomplete - no resources, events etc defined).

Comment: Here's a demo of your code above working nicely with a bootstrap theme: http://jsfiddle.net/toytd26b/29/ - of course I've loaded all the dependencies, in the correct order, required for fullCalendar 3.7, so that may be the difference. I cannot reproduce this "undefined undefined" behaviour at all. Have you got some scripts loading asynchronously, or unreliably? Or it could just be a compatibility thing. Impossible to tell based on the above.

Comment: @ADyson - thank you. Turned out to be a conflict of files from local and remote.